# LDAP only inactive users query

Tags: active-directory, ldap

i have a ldap query that only searchs for active users.
The query is the following:

```
"(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(whenchanged>=#LAST_DAYS#))"
```

I assumed that i only had to remove the "!" to get the inactive users, but i was wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that `(whenchanged>=#LAST_DAYS#)` is correct? If yes, try to query accounts without using userAccountControl and see if it returns more accounts than when you use `=2`. `2` stands for UF_ACCOUNT_DISABLE and corresponds to "Account is disabled" flag in the Account Properties (user may not login to the domain). You can also go to AD and see if accounts have that flag enabled.

[image]